# Postgres 14 - DDL and DML users

Tags: postgresql, ddl, dml

I need to create 2 users for a database and schema, one for DDL queries and the other for DML queries. Is it possible and how can i do it?
I'm running Postgres 14 on windows and pgAdmin to run queries

Kind regards

```
# connected as postgres 
create user tst_ddl with password 'Pwd@123';
create user tst_dml with password 'Pwd@123';

CREATE DATABASE testdb
    WITH
    OWNER = tst_ddl
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252'
    LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
    IS_TEMPLATE = False;

# connected as postgres @testdb
alter default privileges 
   for role tst_ddl
   grant select,update,delete on tables
   to tst_dml;

alter default privileges 
  for role tst_ddl
  in schema tst
  revoke update,select,delete on tables
  from tst_ddl;

 # connected as tst_ddl

CREATE TABLE tst.tb_tsta
(
    col_a integer
);

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS tst.tb_tsta
    OWNER to tst_ddl;
```

running the code above, i can create and alter the table structure but i can query the data also.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you changing which user you're executing queries as? Are you changing your session authorization anywhere to execute queries as either `tst_ddl` or `tst_dml`?

Comment: From the manual: `There is no need to grant privileges to the owner of an object (usually the user that created it), as the owner has all privileges by default.`

Comment: Use the [Grant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) to specify which permission a DB user should have.

Comment: I changed my post to show what user i was using